# How to Join two columns in same table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT CAST(`last_charged_date`  AS DATE) AS Date_time, COUNT(*) AS
```

Charged_Count, SUM(`last_charge_amt`) AS Revenue 
    FROM `subscriber` 
    GROUP BY CAST(`last_charged_date`  AS DATE)

SELECT CAST(`created_date` AS DATE) AS Date_time, COUNT(*) AS Registered_Count 
    FROM `subscriber` 
    GROUP BY CAST(`created_date` AS DATE)

> I want to join `last_charged_date` and `created_date` as one column and need show  Charged_Count, Revenue, and Registered_Count as separate columns according to the date

Comment: Have you considered a `union` ?

Comment: Join is a very loose term - it would help if you could show your expected output.

Comment: @ScaryWombat for `union` both the queries should have same number of columns with same data type.

Comment: Share your sample output

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Of course, you are right.  Adding a dummy column would be trivial though.  Easier to see now that it has been tidied up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all` :

```
select date, 
       sum ( col = 'last_charged' ) as Charged_Count,
       sum (case when col = 'last_charged' then Revenue else 0 end ) as Revenue,
       sum ( col = 'created_date' ) as Registered_Count
from (select CAST(s.`last_charged_date`  AS DATE) as date, 
             s.`last_charge_amt` as Revenue, 'last_charged' as col 
      from `subscriber` s union all
      select CAST(s1.`created_date`  AS DATE) as created_date, 
             0, 'created_date' as col 
      from `subscriber` s1
    ) t
group by date;
```

Answer (score 1):

use subquery and join but for this case in any date less in of the subquery data will be less

```
select a.*,b.* from ( SELECT CAST(`last_charged_date`  AS DATE) AS Date_time, COUNT(*) AS 
 Charged_Count, SUM(`last_charge_amt`) AS Revenue 
    FROM `subscriber` 
    GROUP BY CAST(`last_charged_date`  AS DATE)
) a join 
(
 SELECT CAST(`created_date` AS DATE) AS Date_time, COUNT(*) AS Registered_Count 
    FROM `subscriber` 
    GROUP BY CAST(`created_date` AS DATE)
) b on a.Date_time=b.Date_time
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query,

```
SELECT CAST(`last_charged_date`  AS DATE) AS Date_time, COUNT(*) AS  Charged_Count, SUM(last_charge_amt) AS Revenue, ksolangi.Date_time, Date_time.Registered_Count
FROM subscriber 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT CAST(created_date AS DATE) AS Date_time, COUNT(*) AS Registered_Count FROM subscriber GROUP BY CAST(created_date AS DATE) ) AS ksolangi ON ksolangi.Date_time = CAST(last_charged_date AS DATE)
GROUP BY CAST(last_charged_date AS DATE)
```

Comment: this query is not working for me. Registered_Count can't be used before it assigns as Registered_Count